# Setting a 3rd party cookie through a widget so I can recognize the user later

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, widget, jsonp

I'm trying to set a 3rd party cookie from a widget that users add to their website. The widget is on user-site.com and the hosted code is o admin-site.com. My goal is to set a cookie for them so the widget will recognize them on any website the widget is installed on. I don't want to have to use a popup and have them login through my site. I just want to set a cookie for them VIA the widget and then be able to recognize them.

- 2 lines of code are needed to make the widget appear; 1 .js file and 1 line of html.

Once the widget is added to user-site.com two text fields appear; 1 for your name and 1 for your email. You then click a button to submit. I then return a user_id for the user and attempt to set a cookie through the widget. This isn't working...

### user-site.com needs to add 2 lines of code into their html to make the widget appear

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async="true"></script>
<div id="widget-container" class="8AORPIY0"></div>
```

### widget.js

```
// Create the input fields and submit button
var login_name = '<input type="text" name="name" />';
var login_email = '<input type="email" name="email" />';
var login_button = '<input type="button" value="Login" />';
var add_fields_to_html_snippet = login_name + login_email + login_button;

$('#widget-container').html(add_fields_to_html_snippet);

$.ajax({
    url : "http://example.com/widget_update.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: { name:name, email:email },
    dataType:"jsonp",
    jsonp:"mycallbackupdate",
    success:function(data) { // The server side sends back the users id which will become the value of the 3rd party cookie

        // This is the value *user_id returned from server side
        var value = data.user_id;
        // I'm trying to set a cookie but it doesn't work
        document.cookie = 'cookie1=' + user_id + '; expires=Fri, 3 Aug 2016 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'

        }           
    });
```

How can I successfully set a cookie for the user through the embedded widget? I want to be able to recognize the users from any site that uses this widget.

### Update

I've also tried setting the cookie from the server side:

```
$_COOKIE['user_id'] = $user_id;
$expire = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
setcookie('cookie1', $_COOKIE['user_id'], $expire);
```

But, I'm unable to get the value of `cookie1` from widget.js. I've tried to get the cookie value by using this:

```
alert(document.cookie.indexOf("cookie1")); // This doesn't return the same value I set the cookie to from the HTTP header
```

But, that doesn't return the same value that I set the cookie to in the HTTP header. How can I call the same value in widget.js?

Comment: You can't set a content type on a GET request, there is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: I updated the code and removed that. Is there a way to successfully set a cookie with the updated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript always runs in the context of the HTML document it is embedded in, consequently you cannot set a third party cookie using JavaScript.

Set the cookie using HTTP headers on the JSONP response (keeping in mind that many browsers are configured to block third party cookies entirely).

Comment: Can you please provide a short code sample that would work in widget.js? Thank you Quentin.

Comment: `<?php setcookie("cookie1", $user_id, time()+60*60*24*30, "/");` ?>`

Comment: Ahh yes, I've actually tried that and re-implemented it now. I updated my question with the code example on why I was having an issue with this. I'm unable to get the value of `cookie1` when I try to call it in widget.js. Can you please have a look and let me know why my code isn't working? Thanks you!

Comment: As I said - Javascript only has access to the cookies of the page the code is running in. It can't read or write third party cookies. If you want the cookie data available to the JS then you have to output it from your server side code.

Comment: From widget.js though, what type of variable would I store the cookie value in where I would know it's been set from any website the widget is embedded on? (even with a page reload, etc.)

Comment: Or, could I write an ajax function to see if the cookie has been set VIA HTTP and return the value?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Cookies will always be strings. If you want to set one from a third party website then you must cause an HTTP request to be made to the domain the cookie is for. If you want to read it, then you must do so with server side code on the domain the cookie is for. If you want to read it on another site, then you must output the value of the cookie in a format that can be read by the other site (such as a string in a JSON document with CORS headers granting permission to the other site to read it).

Answer (score 0):

Set the cookie from `widget_update.php`.

You should set the "secure" attribute (assuming admin-site.com is served over HTTPS) to prevent people from stealing that info if the end user is on public WiFi.

You also need to set the SameSite attribute to "None". Modern browsers are trying to improve internet security and prevent data from leaking, so cookies could be blocked if you don't specifically say it is allowed on third party websites with "samesite=none".